# Why do I get "Connection was refused by the server" when using Thunder Client on VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, thunderclient

I'm using [Thunder Client](https://www.thunderclient.com/) on Visual Studio Code, and tried making a request to "localhost:3000".

It gave me an error

> Connection was refused by the server

Any fix to this?

Answer (score 32):

Using SvelteKit, VSCode and Thunder Client

Example that didn't work for me:
localhost:5173/api/posts

Solved by using
[::1]:5173/api/posts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Any reason why this hack would work? I am facing the same issues in another extension called `REST Client`, `localhost`, and `127.0.0.1` doesn't work at all but `[::1]` gives some different error regarding `TLS`.

Comment: I was facing the same connection refused issue on ThunderClient that got resolved when used `[::1]` in place of localhost, e.g., `http://[::1]:8000/api/`

Answer (score 5):

The npm / pnpm server has an option that exposes the host.  Testing with a browser a test GET /hello route works with

```
http://localhost:5173/hello
```

But in Thunderclient it can not access the server

Connection was refused by the server.

Oddly, `npm run dev --host` also refused the connection but

```
pnpm run dev --host
```

works with Thunderclient

also

```
bun run dev --host
```

also works.  If your routes are already setup with localhost, using the --host switch with pnpm or bun is a good solution.

I do prefer the modern alternatives to npm as they are far more for far less (less file activity, and much faster).  They are easy to install and work exactly the same with vite.

But, with both pnpm and bun, without --host, localhost is not exposed to Thunderclient, but `[::1]` works uniformly in npm/pnpm/bun without the --host option.

So, oddly, this is the easiest and best answer at this time:

```
http://[::1]:5173/api/route
```

This, of course, looks like a bug and may change in time.  Tested on a Macos platform, may or may not be the same as Windows.  I expect Linux just works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

1. if you are using WSL on Windows use [::1] instead of localhost in the address bar. Example [::1]:3000/api/v1 .
2. Another option is to use the PowerShell instead of the WSL terminal.
3. You can also move your project directory to the Linux file system (~/home)

Answer (score 1):

You are facing this problem because of backend you juts have to start your backend and also make sure you have install body-parser

Answer (score 0):

Please use your IP address instead of localhost: `ipaddress:port`.

Then, it might work. Eg. `192.168.0.1:3000`

For more information see our support page comment

https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support/issues/251#issuecomment-874439967

> But instead of using `localhost:9000` I did use the actual IP set for the computer… `198.168.0.189:9000` for example, then it works.

Comment: Hello... I have this same issue but my endpoint is not a localhost endpoint. The server domain is an actual IP address internal to our company. Also, if I start a REST server locally and use the same endpoint with localhost... I have no issue actually. Only with the server on the network. Also it's not just this particular server, all my endpoints on the various servers have this same issue. Localhost no issue. The "solution" you propose in the link above does not apply nor work for my case. :(

Comment: Joseph create an issue on our Thunder Client GitHub page, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Django here and sending request to

```
127.0.0.1:8000/
```

instead of

```
localhost:8000/
```

works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the FQDN with http:// instead of https://

That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found the solution (at least in Node/Express), indirectly thanks to Ranga Vadhineni's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70919413/20237611). Since I can't explain why this happens, I will just explain my train of thought on how I figured it out.

```
Connection was refused by the server.
```

Ugh, Thunder Client was again giving me trouble requesting to `localhost`, changing the request URL to `127.0.0.1` didn't help, tried to use my local IP **with all that implies**.

1. Change the URL in Thunder to `192.168.0.10`
2. Enable the rule in Windows' firewall to allow incoming requests for Node.js
3. **Change my server's listening host from "localhost" to `0.0.0.0`**
4. Voilà!

But... that didn't make much sense, and it's also a huge limitation, there has to be something going on. I tried changing Thunder's URL back to `127.0.0.1`, and it worked... *huh!?* How about `localhost`? It worked! *Eh!?*

Rushed back to my serve's configuration and changed the host back to `localhost`. As expected this time, Thunder got a connection refused; keep in mind that both Postman and Insomia didn't have a problem with this, only Thunder! But then again Thunder reports the problem being on the server...

Instead of using `localhost` for my host *in the server's configuration*, I tried `127.0.0.1`... voilà...

## TL;DR

Thunder Client can handle both `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` in the URL with no problem, the issue seems to be (at least in Node/Express) in the server itself.

Simply change the server's host, so that instead of listening to `localhost`, it listens to `127.0.0.1`.

**If anybody can provide an explanation as to why this works, please do so, I'm at a lost here**

Answer (score 0):

When we open the Visual Studio Code, the remote access option is automatically activated.

[Remote Windown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0Abj.png)

To work perfectly, it will depend on where your application is running. For example, if running directly on windows, close the remote vs code connection.

[Click on the blue button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwkhE.png)

Then select the option "close remote connection".

[Close Remote Windown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nror5.png)

Answer (score 0):

express validator

```
 routers.post('/',[
        body('name').isLength({min:3}),
        body('password').isLength({min:5}),
        body('email').isEmail(),
    ],(req,res)=>{
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
          return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }
    
        res.send(req.body); 
    
        
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue you need to explicitly define the host name in package.json file.

```
"dev-server": "json-server --watch ./db.json -p 3200 -H 127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change server host to `'0.0.0.0'` instead of `'localhost'`

This work for me

Answer (score 0):

There is fix to this "Connection refused by server". The problem arises because of my the address.
You can change your IP address in mongodb to allow access from anywhere by setting 0.0.0.0 and your error will be solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If any one of the above answers doesn't solve your issue, then maybe you are having errors because of the undefined port number the server listens to. First check the port number if it is defined correctly.

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at port: ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

If you try to set your port like the way mentioned above, then you must tell the port number to node environment through command line before running the script for server otherwise you will get the "server refused to connect" error if your port number is undefined.
For simplicity, you can just define your port number by declaring a variable to "process.env.PORT || xxxx" and using that in the server's listener function.

```
const port = process.env.PORT || xxxx;
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running at port: ${port}`);
```

This way the node environment will set the port number from the environment variables if there any PORT exists or xxxx will be used.